# Error: socket hang up - как найти виновника

Tags: node.js

Доброго времени суток!

Время от времени ловлю в логах приложения такую бяку:

```
    /node_modules/q/q.js:155
                throw e;
                ^

Error: socket hang up
    at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1049:19)
    at TLSSocket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:397:17)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #1
```

Есть идеи как вычислить виновника катастрофы и/или не вылетать с критической ошибкой?

Answer (score 1):

Не вылетать с критической ошибкой можно с помощью

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Но надо учесть, что критические ошибки потому и критические, что после них с некоторой вероятностью некоторые вещи перестанут работать. Поэтому всё же стоит добавить в обработчик нечто вроде

```
switch(err.code){
    case #какой то определённый код ошибки#:
        //код который исправляет последствия ошибки
    break;
    case #какой то определённый код другой ошибки#:
        //код который исправляет последствия другой ошибки
    break;
    default:
        throw err; //Всё пошло совсем не так, вылетаем
}
```

Comment: сейчас используется process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.error('uncaughtException: ', err.message)
  console.error(err.stack)
}); Стека нет, вылет есть, откуда вызывается виновник - не понятно...

Answer (score 1):

socket hang up не является фатальной ошибкой и не кидается в качестве исключения.

Если оно каким-то образом оказалось кинуто в качестве исключения - значит, у вас в коде есть конструкция `throw` в обработчике ошибок. Уберите ее оттуда.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно это [ошибка клиента](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_clienterror). Также здесь сказано что если сокет недоступен для записи, он немедленно уничтожается, поэтому в данном случае виновника найти не удастся. Иногда это происходит по причине отсутствия поддержки какого нибудь звена на стороне клиента (к сожалению не могу точно сказать чего, пока сам изучаю). В таком случае сервер с клиентом договариваются между собой о новом соединении, которое поддерживают обе стороны. И в случае удачного соединения, сокет клиента придет уже с другим портом.

Вот пример, в котором я отсылаю заброс на API-интерфейс с помощью `Postman` используя SSL / TLS соединение и необходимого сертификата.

```
172.17.0.1:43610 (onClientConnection)
172.17.0.1:43614 (onClientConnection)
undefined:undefined (onClientError) => Error: socket hang up
172.17.0.1:43614 (onClientRequest) [ POST ] /v1/bill/encode-ccard
172.17.0.1:43614 (onClientData) 371 b 
172.17.0.1:43614 (onClientEnd) >> encodeCcard()
172.17.0.1:43614 (onClientClose) 200 OK
```

Из этого лог-файла можно увидеть что произошло два соединения. Но прежде чем ошибка успела отработать, сокет уже был уничтожен и подсоединен с другого порта. А две подстроки с текстом `undefined` свидетельствуют о том, что сокета уже не существует.